# String function in c

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

I was writing a simple string function. The problem is: I declare a char pointer, then once I try to update a specific character, the program crashes.

I have checked some previously written string processing, I found that they modify specific characters. But when I try to run them, I get the same problem.

Sample:

```
   stringprocess()
{
 char *s;
 s=" I am c programmer";
 s=" but, ..... um";

 *s='x'; //program crashes here...

 *p="abc";
 *s=*p; // this also cause crashing
........
}
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

```
s=" but, ..... um";
```

`s` points to a string literal. Trying to modify a string literal invokes undefined behaviour. Often, string literals are stored in read-only memory, then a crash is the immediate consequence of such an attempt.

You should use a `char s[100]` (just for example) or a `malloc`ed pointer if you want to modify the contents.